# Simulating network failures with QNetworkAccessManager & QNetworkReply

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply, qhttp

I'm using Qt4.8 and I want to inject network faults into pre-existing code that uses QNetworkAccessManager.  However, this class - and particularly the related QNetworkReply seem to have some strange semantics.  I created a subclass of QNetworkAccessManager as well as one of QNetworkReply.  My QTestNetworkAccessManager returns either an object created by the base QNetworkAccessManager, or the next test reply in the list:

```
QNetworkReply *QTestNetworkAccessManager
       ::createRequest( Operation op,
                        const QNetworkRequest &req,
                        QIODevice * outgoingData )
{
    // QList<QTestNetworkReply*> m_replies;
    if (m_replies.isEmpty())
    {
        return QNetworkAccessManager::
                  createRequest( op, req, outgoingData );
    }
    QTestNetworkReply* pReply = m_replies.takeFirst();
    pReply->setUrl(req.url()); // lie about URLs
    // this sets a timer that fires finished, etc.
    pReply->queueFinished();
    return pReply;
}
```

In the simple, trivial case of a single request, my test code seems to work, but  two problems show up when I put it in a bigger app doing lots of network traffic.

First is QNetworkAccessManager seems to have private knowledge of the QNetworkReply objects it's creating. (based on inspecting the Qt source).  For example it creates various flavors of QHttpReplyImpl and various other Impl objects and hooks them up in various ways, so my test objects don't seem to be good citizens in that environment.  This seems to cause problems like error() signals not propagating correctly and my memory space is experiencing stack corruption.

(I'm not posting the entire QTextNetworkReply object because it's pretty simple and my question isn't really to troubleshoot my specific code.)

My question is:  Has anyone done this kind of fault injection with QNetworkAccessManager and been able to simulate various HTTP faults.

One thought was to use the HttpProxy hooks to create a proxy server that actually injects data at the socket level so that it traverses the entire QHttp* object parser, but that seems like a lot of trouble.

Is there really no easier way to inject faults into QNetworkAccessManager so it acts like it is talking to a live server?

Thanks!

P.S. I am familiar with https://blogs.kde.org/2010/08/28/implementing-reusable-custom-qnetworkreply which is why I went down the road I'm on of subclassing QNAM, but it doesn't seem to handle the error semantics correctly and the gitorious link to the code is broken.